# Magento 2 styling issues after switch from default to production mode

Tags: permissions, production-mode, magento-2.2.1

I thought I should switch to **production mode** from **default mode** as I got closer to **launching my site**. As soon as I did that, the formatting of my front-end and admin section got messed up. The front end is like one column now, almost like a mobile phone version of the site, but not even that nicely styled.

**The image below is while still in default mode:**

[image: While still in default mode]

[image: After changing modes from default to production]

**The image above is after the switch to production mode.**

The admin section is screwed up also like it has no formatting at all.

URL: [www.warmanuals.com](http://www.warmanuals.com)

Magento version is 2.2.1. I am also using the Porto theme. The Porto people said it looks like a permissions issue, so the last thing I did was follow the directions here, for setting production permissions in a shared hosting environment where you can only have one user. This procedure did not change anything.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Remove CSS and JS merger form Admin

Comment: Have you tried redeploying as i found in 2.2.1 that it didnt deploy correctly also i had to set perms on pub static folder to 777 as for some reason it wasnt happy with the recommended permissions set out in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

When you change to developer or production mode, the following directories are cleared..

- var/cache
- var/di
- var/generation
- var/view_preprocessed
- pub/static

This link may help you understand further.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2584